# How to fix dyld: Library not loaded error

Tags: ios, xcode

I have used Xcode7.3.1, add a framework to my project,then build error,
Error message :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/youare.framework/youare
Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/823267F9-AA33-4518-98B1-B4E6C7D239F7/we.app/we
 Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/823267F9-AA33-4518-98B1-B4E6C7D239F7/we.app/Frameworks/youare.framework/youare: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/823267F9-AA33-4518-98B1-B4E6C7D239F7/we.app/Frameworks/youare.framework/youare'
```

I have  installed the renewed certificate AppleWWDRCA,but have the same error.

Comment: Try clean and build.

Comment: @Mr.UB have tried, same error